# operate through subarrays of an array recursively merging them (python)

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

I have this question:
if you have an array of arrays, lets say, like this

```
A = [[1, 2], [3, 6, 8, 1], [2, 4, 7]]
```

how is it possible to perform an operation between the first two subarrays and write the result as a new subarray which occupies the place of the two old ones so that the operation can be recursively re-computed between this new sub array and the one next to it until we only get one array?

Comment: Is there a requirement for recursion? Otherwise, the more efficient, simpler approach is just: `from itertools import chain`, `A = list(chain(*A))`. Avoids tons of intermediate `list`s (`array` is something totally different and special purpose in Python, `list` of `list`s is what you're using), and should run significantly faster than any `reduce` based approach. If you need to maintain the doubly-nested thing (with a single inner `list`), just wrap in brackets: `A = [list(chain(*A))]`

Comment: Can you an some expected output for certain functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing a `reduce` operation: take two items, apply some operation to them, then take the result and apply the same operation to it with the next item, and so on. Fortunately, `reduce` is such a fundamental concept in functional programming that python has a built-in for it:

```
def unique_append(left, right):
  return left + [elem for elem in right if elem not in left]
  # Example only! Don't do this with lists, use sets!

arr = [[1, 2], [3, 6, 8, 1], [2, 4, 7]]
print reduce(unique_append, arr)  
# [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 4, 7]
```

This doesn't replace the first two sub-arrays with the result, but instead carries the intermediate result all the way until the last sub-array and then returns the final result. It also doesn't involve recursion, which is not required here.

If you insist on changing the original array in-place, you can do this (which will be inefficient and slow for various reasons):

```
# Slow, inefficient example
while len(arr) > 1:
  arr[:2] = some_operation(arr[0], arr[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Recurse on your `list` of `list`'s performing the operation on the first two items and returning when there is only on `list` left.

```
add = lambda l1, l2: sum(l1 + l2)


def func(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst
    lst = [[add(lst[0], lst[1])]] + lst[2:]
    return func(lst)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lst = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
    print(func(lst))
```

This will print:

```
[[45]]
```

On each call to `func` the first two list items have your "operation" applied (here it is summing of the two).  Then the result is put into another list, trimming the last two off and this is repeated recursively calling the function until there is only a `list` of one remaining.

As others have noted this is a more complicated and less efficient way to do this.  I found myself reaching for `reduce` and `itertools` when starting to make a small example to base my response on but, without more detail of your exact use case and situation I made this to show what it was you asked.